# Create list using C# CSOM in a subsite on Office SharePoint O365

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, csom

We have a SharePoint 2013 Provider-Hosted App using C# CSOM that has been deployed to a Developer site under the root site. One of the requirements of our app is that it should be able to create lists in the site where the app is deployed and trusted as well as to subsites below this site, once the user has access. However, when trying to create a list on a subsite of the developer site we get a 403 Forbidden error.

Is there any way to create lists on subsites from our app or am I only able to create lists on the site my app was deployed to?

Comment: Did you ever solve you problem ? What client context did you use to create the lists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an AppOnlyAccessToken (`TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken()`) to do this, as well as allow the app to make App-Only calls in SharePoint.